# Dropdown menu in bootstrap 3.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

atully i just strated in bootstrap . as i have taken the same template found here

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/

bootstrap version 3.2.0

in this template whne i push the nav bar buttons to right the drop down menu stop working . once done . again if i  change code it stop working nd never works. wht i m doing is simply changing

```
class=" nav navbar-nav nav" . to class=" nav navbar-nav navbar-right"
```

my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

<title>Admission Portal</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap theme -->
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

 </head>

   <body role="document">

  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
     <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Admission portal</a>
      </div>
       <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
           </li>
         </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okk finally i found my answer of my own question . first of all bootstrap is based on java script so you will be needing to include all java script files . specially th jquery.min .so i was lacking that. if u want more info on the same

question refrence is on 
[Bootstrap dropdown menu not working (not dropping down when clicked)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345714/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-not-working-not-dropping-down-when-clicked?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"</script>
```

just add this line in your code it will start working.
Note: Add this line before bootstrap.min.js line