# Bootstrap button not working (not opening when clicking)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Below is my snippet for using Bootstrap which contains a single drop-down button. Any idea why it is not working? (when I click it just doesn't open anything).

I saw similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345714/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-not-working-not-dropping-down-when-clicked) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458522/bootstrap-dropdown-not-working). But none of the suggested solutions solutions solved my problem.

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Bootstrap 3 </title>
        <link href ="css/bootstrap.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href ="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href ="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href ="css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body> 


        <!-- Single button -->
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Action <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>


    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Are you testing it locally and maybe jquery isn't loaded? I just created this bootply http://www.bootply.com/q6r1f5tZJU with your markup and it's working.

Comment: But this part: "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" doesn't it mean that it will load the jquery from web?

Comment: Not necessarily, it just means that it will use the protocol from the page - if the page protocol is `http`, it will be loaded from `http://` (and same with `https`) - you should check web dev net console if jquery is loaded or, what is possible, if the page tries to load e.g. from `file://` instead of `http://` in case you're running it locally. For local testing, add `http://` or download jquery and load it local like you're already doing with bootstrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cannot recognize jquery.js file. Please change this

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why ??? This is so wrong and its even against the official instruction http://jquery.com/download/#using-jquery-with-a-cdn